# removeClass with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, removeclass

I am trying to use the remove class function. My jQuery code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.hidden").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Page</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="testing.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="hidden">Hello World</h1>
        <div>Dog</div>
        <div class="hidden">Cat</div>
        <div>Girl</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is not working as expected. I expected all divs with the class of hidden to have the class removed thereby causing the divs to be displayed.

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: `("div.hidden").removeClass("hidden");` ????? missing `$`

Comment: Please learn checking the error console of your browser.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple syntax error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the jQuery obj to call your selector :

```
$("div.hidden").removeClass("hidden"); //$(selector);
```

Comment: Oh wow that was stupid. Sorry for the horrible question. Thanks!!!